# The gamma parameter (or kernel width) for RBF Gaussian kernel in kernel PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

Is there any general way or rule of thumb of how to determine the kernel width for KPCA?